# Spark Mongodb: Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoDriverInformation

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am working with Spark-shell using Mongo-spark-connector to read/write data into MongoDB, while I am facing the below error, besides placing the required JARS as follows, can someone find what the problem is and help me out!

Thank you in advance

Jars:

```
mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar;
mongodb-driver-sync-3.11.0.jar;
mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar; 
mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar;
mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar;
mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.7.jar
```

**Error:**

```
scala> MongoSpark.save(dfRestaurants.write.option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://username:password@server_name").option("spark.mongodb.output.database", "admin").option("spark.mongodb.output.collection", "myCollection").mode("overwrite"));

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoDriverInformation**
at com.mongodb.spark.connection.DefaultMongoClientFactory.mongoDriverInformation$lzycompute(DefaultMongoClientFactory.scala:40)
  at com.mongodb.spark.connection.DefaultMongoClientFactory.mongoDriverInformation(DefaultMongoClientFactory.scala:40)
  at com.mongodb.spark.connection.DefaultMongoClientFactory.create(DefaultMongoClientFactory.scala:49)
  at com.mongodb.spark.connection.MongoClientCache.acquire(MongoClientCache.scala:55)
  at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.acquireClient(MongoConnector.scala:242)
  at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withMongoClientDo(MongoConnector.scala:155)
  at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withDatabaseDo(MongoConnector.scala:174)
  at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withCollectionDo(MongoConnector.scala:187)
  at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
  at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$.save(MongoSpark.scala:192)
  ... 59 elided
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem when you have incorrect dependencies.  In your case:

1. Mongo Spark Connector 2.2.7 was built with driver 3.10/3.11, so it could be incompatible with driver 3.4
2. you have 2 different versions of Mongo Spark Connector - 2.2.0 & 2.2.7 - this also could lead to problems

The better solution is to pass Maven coordinates in `--packages` option when starting spark shell, and allow Spark pull the package with all necessary & correct dependencies:

```
spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:<version>
```

please make sure that you're using the Scala version that is matching your Spark version (2.12 for Spark 3.0, 2.11 for previous versions). See [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala-api/) for more details.