# Azure Databricks loading mongodb using pyspark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to get mongodb data (2gb) comments dataset to Azure databricks. It did run the first time  and I was able to get the data (so guessing my connection string and the code is correct) but after that I keep getting the same error every-time I try to run it. I'm unable to resolve it. I tried but couldn't find much resources around it.

````
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
database = database_name
collection = collection_name
connectionString= connection_string
spark=SparkSession.builder.config('spark.mongodb.input.uri',connectionString).config('spark.mongodb.input.uri', connectionString).config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1').getOrCreate()


###### Reading from MongoDB
df=spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri",connectionString).option("database", database).option("collection", collection).load() ```

Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 23) (10.139.64.6 executor 0): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.checkDatabaseNameValidity(Ljava/lang/String;)

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2293330354451765> in <module>
      1 # Reading from MongoDB
----> 2 df=spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri",connectionString).option("database", database).option("collection", collection).load()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    208             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    209         else:
--> 210             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    211 
    212     def json(self, path, schema=None, primitivesAsString=None, prefersDecimal=None,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o459.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 23) (10.139.64.6 executor 0): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.checkDatabaseNameValidity(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:371)
    at com.mongodb.spark.connection.DefaultMongoClientFactory.create(DefaultMongoClientFactory.scala:50)
    at com.mongodb.spark.connection.MongoClientCache.acquire(MongoClientCache.scala:55)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.acquireClient(MongoConnector.scala:239)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.compute(MongoRDD.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1620)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2828)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2775)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2769)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1305)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3036)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2965)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2477)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2460)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2572)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1232)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoInferSchema$.apply(MongoInferSchema.scala:88)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.constructRelation(DefaultSource.scala:97)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:400)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:400)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:273)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoNamespace.checkDatabaseNameValidity(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:371)
    at com.mongodb.spark.connection.DefaultMongoClientFactory.create(DefaultMongoClientFactory.scala:50)
    at com.mongodb.spark.connection.MongoClientCache.acquire(MongoClientCache.scala:55)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.acquireClient(MongoConnector.scala:239)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.compute(MongoRDD.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1620)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
````

Comment: Welcome!     What version of the mongodb java client-side driver are you using?

Comment: you have a problem with dependencies - add a list of libraries that you're using, plus a version of Databricks Runtime

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880459/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-mongodb-internal-connection-cluster-selectserve/68882963#68882963 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374213/spark-mongodb-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-mongodb-mongodriverin/63994972#63994972

Answer (score 0):

on my case i have this cenary

The conection

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2') \
    .getOrCreate() 

mongo_df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("database", mongo_DB).option("collection", mongo_collection).load()
mongo_df.createOrReplaceTempView('collection')
```

But you need to register your spark.mongodb.input.uri and output.uri
like this:

```
spark.mongodb.input.uri <your_connection_string>
spark.mongodb.output.uri <your_connection_string>
```

on your cluster config, like on print

[image]